# A way to pass variables (record ids) to jQuery event listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

Suppose I generate a list of records on my web page via PHP, and suppose each has a link beside it. And let's say that a modal window pops up when I click the link, and an edit form then shows in the modal.

I could easily make this happen like this:

```
<a href="javascript:showEditModal(12345)">Edit</a>
```

But I'd prefer to use a jQuery event listener:

```
<a class="edit" href="#">edit</a>

$('.edit').click(function(event) {
  showEditModal(recordId);
});
```

As you can see, using an event listener, I do not have a way of knowing which record the user wants to edit via the modal.

How can I allow the user to specify which record to edit while still using an event listener for the edit links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a class="edit" href="#12345">edit</a>

$('.edit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  recordId = $(this).attr("href").substr(1);
  showEditModal(recordId);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This is not as semantic as SLaks' suggestion. Why are you using the href?

Answer (score 4):

If using jQuery >= 1.4.3, you can specify a "data-id" attribute (HTML5! woohoo) on the link and grab it using jQuery's data() method:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('a.edit').click(function() {
    alert( $(this).data('id') );
  });
});
</script>
<a href="#" class="edit" data-id="12345">edit</a>
```

And [here's a demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akCrY/).

Comment: I really like this solution, but I'm not sure of browser support.

Comment: AFAIK, it works in every major browser, even IE6.  I've not encountered any issues thus far, and I use data-* attributes quite often now.  Even if you are using a HTML4 doctype, they may not be *valid*, but they still work.

Answer (score 3):

Put the ID in an attribute of the element.

Comment: This works, but I really don't like this method because it's not the original design intent for the 'id' attribute of HTML elements.