# chrome extension - manifest version 2

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I developed manifest version 1 of a chrome extension which takes input from user and open a new window

But when I upgraded to manifest version 2 the redirection to www.someUrl.com in a new tab is stopped.

Please tell me what changes I have to do according to version 2 to make it run.

popup.html

```html
<body onload="document.form.query.focus()";>

<div id="searchwrapper">

<script>
function send_url() {   
    var url = "www.someurl.com?query="+form.query.value;
    window.open(url, '_blank'); 
    return false;
}
</script>
<form name="form" id="search_form" action="popup.html" method="POST">
<input type="text" class="searchbox" name="query" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="search" value="1">
<input type="image" src="search.png" onClick="send_url()" value=""/>
</form>
</div>

</body>
```

and my manifest.json

```js
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Search",
"version": "2.0",
"description": "This is a chrome extension for search",
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": ["www.someUrl.com"]
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Content-Security-Policy error in google chrome extension making](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045653/content-security-policy-error-in-google-chrome-extension-making)

Comment: Take a look at this question. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473405/a-way-to-pass-variables-record-ids-to-jquery-event-listeners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No inline scripts is allowed in Manifest2. 
Manifest 2 also disallow

`onClick="send_url()"`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
"version": "2.0",
```

to

```
  "manifest_version": 2,
```

Comment: `version` and `manifest_version` are totally different. The first one refers to _your_ extension version, the second one to the manifest version.